# How to make dictionary to output by max value only (implied_volatility)?

Tags: python, dictionary, finance, computational-finance

So the dictionary titled 'option' spits out the result (tradeable options) below by strike_price, ask_price, delta and implied_volatility. But I don't need it to spit out all of the tradeable options. I only want the output to show me 1 tradeable option that has the highest implied_volatility (IV), so for example, the result should only show the option with the highest IV:

*Strike Price: 43.0000, Ask: 0.030000, Bid: 0.000000, Delta: 0.008705, IV: 1.449510* - because IV here is the highest from the entire output below.

How can I do this?

```
import config 
import robin_stocks as r 

r.login(config.USERNAME,config.PASSWORD)


#specify criteria to search for options of a given symbol and its exp date
symbol = 'GDX'
expirationDate = '2020-06-19'


search_option = r.find_options_for_stock_by_expiration(symbol,expirationDate,optionType='call')


for option in search_option:

        print("Strike Price: {}, Ask: {}, Bid: {}, Delta: {}, IV: {}".format(option['strike_price'],option['ask_price'],option['bid_price'],option['delta'], option['implied_volatility']))


**OUTPUT**:
Strike Price: 42.0000, Ask: 0.030000, Bid: 0.000000, Delta: 0.009354, IV: 1.335719
Strike Price: 43.0000, Ask: 0.030000, Bid: 0.000000, Delta: 0.008705, IV: 1.449510
Strike Price: 35.5000, Ask: 0.060000, Bid: 0.040000, Delta: 0.073395, IV: 0.634361
Strike Price: 36.5000, Ask: 0.030000, Bid: 0.020000, Delta: 0.041370, IV: 0.743600
```

Comment: Let me make sure. Do you need to choose only an option with the highest IV value?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: The current answer's complexity is somewhat hight. Let me post an improved solution. It will `O(n)`

Comment: I posted my answer. Would you like to give it a shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the place of `for` loop of your code replace this one.

```
highest_IV, highest_idx = 0, None
for idx, option in enumerate(search_option):
    if option['implied_volatility'] and highest_IV < float(option['implied_volatility']):
        highest_IV = float(option['implied_volatility'])
        highest_idx = idx
if highest_idx is not None:
    print("Strike Price: {strike_price}, Ask: {ask_price}, Bid: {bid_price}, Delta: {delta}, IV: {implied_volatility}".format(**search_option[highest_idx]))
```

Here, you may need to consider the case that `search_option` is empty.

I hope this would help you.

Comment: I got this error: if highest['implied_volatility'] < option['implied_volatility']:             
               TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Is there any case that `implied_volatility` can be `None`?

Comment: Ah yes! I completely forgot about the fact that I also wanted to exclude the Nones! My apologies on that one

Comment: I updated the code but not sure if this has any syntax or bug case. But would you give it a shot and let me know.

Comment: So I fixed the syntax and I thought it would all work until it spat this out:        
print("Strike Price: {strike_price}, Ask: {ask_price}, Bid: {bid_price}, Delta: {delta}, IV: {implied_volatility}".format(search_option[highest_idx]))
KeyError: 'strike_price'

Comment: But I double checked and 'strike_price' is the correct key in the dictionary. What the hell!

Comment: Ah, just a moment, my code had a small bug. Let me fix it shortly.

Comment: Corrected. Please try again.

Comment: Oh wait it gives me a full list of these options now haha with high IV I guess!                      Strike Price: 28.5000, Ask: 4.450000, Bid: 4.300000, Delta: 0.987135, IV: 0.876913
Strike Price: 42.0000, Ask: 0.030000, Bid: 0.000000, Delta: 0.009185, IV: 1.374517
Strike Price: 43.0000, Ask: 0.030000, Bid: 0.000000, Delta: 0.008567, IV: 1.487969
Strike Price: 50.0000, Ask: 0.010000, Bid: 0.000000, Delta: 0.006106, IV: 2.190367
Strike Price: 8.0000, Ask: 24.950000, Bid: 24.800000, Delta: 0.998303, IV: 7.164647

Comment: I've literally been trying to fix this myself for the past 6 hours so I'm still super grateful for your code haha!

Comment: I guess you might have written the last if statement within the `for` loop?

Comment: It works fully now! You have no idea how much time and sweat you've saved me from, buddy :D! Super vote!

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the option with the highest IV doing something like this:

```py
def find_highest_iv(search_option):
    max_iv = max([option['implied_volatility'] for option in search_option ])
    for option in search_option:
        for k,v in option.items():
            if k == 'implied_volatility' and v == max_iv:
                return option
```

If there are two options with the same IV this will return the first one found in `search_options`. There's probably a more pythonic shorthand way to do this, but this should work.